# com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found with App Engine using Android

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

Our app is based on Google App Engine.

For some weird reasons calling very few methods on Android does not work while it does on web and iOS. This leaves us to believe there is no issue with the backend (deployment, version, etc...).

Calling the same method through api explorer works as expected. We do not see any log in StackDriver as well.

All this method does is to return the roles the user has. We do not suspect parameters (eg. ordering, annotations, etc...) as this method does not require any parameter.

We are at latest SDK and use Android Studio 3.2.2.
[image]

**Android Emulator trace:**

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1065)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
at com.app.android.LoginActivity$userRoleAsyncTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:413)
at com.app.android.LoginActivity$userRoleAsyncTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:385)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

**Android code:**

```
@Override
protected UserRole doInBackground(String... params) {
    UserRole response = null;
    try {
        UserEndpoint.Builder builder = new 
        UserEndpoint.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new GsonFactory(), null);
        builder.setHttpRequestInitializer(new HttpRequestInitializer(){
            @Override
            public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {
                HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
                httpHeaders.set("JSESSIONID", prefs.getCookie());
                request.setHeaders(httpHeaders);
            }
        });

        UserEndpoint service = builder.build();
        response = service.getRoles().execute();
        LogUtil.debug("getRole Response: " + response.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Could not get UserRole", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

**App Engine code:**

```
@ApiMethod(name = "getRoles", path = "getRoles", httpMethod = HttpMethod.GET)
public UserRole getRoles(HttpServletRequest request) throws DatabaseException, IOException {

    //retrieve session and do not create if it does not exist
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    UserRole userRole = null;

    if (session != null){

        //retrieve user from session
        User user = (User) session.getAttribute("user");
        userRole = new UserRole(true, user.getIsActive(), user.getHasChild());
    }

    return userRole;
}
```

**App Engine Explorer**

[image]

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Not sure why this question is being down voted?? Looked at all posts and couldn't find anything related to this question. As I said, the backend is working on other platforms. The fact that only very few methods are not working on Android is intriguing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the root url to this method fixed the issue.

```
builder.setHttpRequestInitializer(new HttpRequestInitializer(){
    @Override
    public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.set("JSESSIONID", prefs.getCookie());
        request.setHeaders(httpHeaders);
  }
});

builder.setRootUrl("https://android-app-backend.appspot.com/_ah/api/");
UserEndpoint service = builder.build();
response = service.getRoles().execute();
```

where android-app-backend corresponds to your own Project ID.
https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/legacy/v1/java/helloendpoints-android-studio